# How can I make previous commits look like they are being worked on live?

Tags: git, shell, push, git-rebase, git-reset

Let's assume that a series of commits were made throughout the day:

```
[1:00pm] $ commit -am "commit 1"
[2:00pm] $ commit -am "commit 2"
[3:00pm] $ commit -am "commit 3"
```

Instead of pushing all of these commits at once, I would like to replay the commits, while pushing each one at delayed times.

How can I push each commit one at a time with new future time stamps, so that it appears to the upstream, that changes are being worked on live?

```
[1:00pm] $ commit -am "commit 1"
[2:00pm] $ commit -am "commit 2"
[3:00pm] $ commit -am "commit 3"

[3:00pm] $ ./begin-pushing

[4:00pm] $ push; #upstream sees commit 1 was done at 4:00pm
[5:00pm] $ push; #upstream sees commit 2 was done at 5:00pm
[6:00pm] $ push; #upstream sees commit 3 was done at 6:00pm
```

Comment: One of the fundamental aspects of Git is that when a commit is made, everything about that commit (including the timestamps) is set in stone. Changing any information (such as a timestamp) requires creating a new commit with a new identity (new sha1) which reflect your new desired timestamp information.

Comment: @GregHewgill I agree that this is not something very common in normal git workflows.  However, a lot of people already do similar behaviour when rewinding with rebase.  My commits in this situation are less 'set in stone', because they have not yet been pushed upstream.

Comment: Ok, sure you could certainly use rebase for this. See [Change timestamps while rebasing git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579643/change-timestamps-while-rebasing-git-branch) for example.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: In addition to the comment by @GregHewgill you may find more example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454734/how-can-one-change-the-timestamp-of-an-old-commit-in-git